# Are files in a .zip file always compressed?

Tags: java, compression, zip, compressed-files

At work I'm implementing a new webservice that works with files. The specifications say that we should not accept .zip files if they are compressed.

Is there such a thing as a not compressed .zip file? If yes, what do you think would be the best way to detect one using Java (1.8)?

Comment: ZipFile package.  And yes, there is a format in there for uncompressed. ZipEntry.STORED

Comment: From Wikipedia: "ZIP allows contained files to be compressed using many different methods, as well as simply storing a file without compressing it"

Answer (score 6):

Yes, a zip can be uncompressed. In fact, early `.jar` files were just uncompressed `.zip` files.

The `ZipEntry` class has [`getMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getMethod()) to get the compression method of an entry. One of the options is [`STORED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#STORED) (e.g., not compressed).

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea about this. I'm just curious about one thing tough, would every entry inside a zip file be either stored or not? I do think so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Pistacchio - Every entry in a zip has its own flag for whether and how it's compressed, yes. So to disallow a "compressed zip," you'd need to check every entry in the zip to see if any of them is compressed (well, you only need to check every one until you find one that's compressed). The vast majority of the time you'll probably find that they're all compressed with the same algorithm, or all uncompressed, but the format allows differences in compression per-entry.

Answer (score 1):

zip is just a container-format, which can hold many possible types of compressed and uncompressed entries.

Often files are `deflated`, which means, they are compressed. Others are simply `stored`, which means they are uncompressed.